# pentaho set up to AWS Aurora ( mysql ) bastion

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, pentaho-spoon

I am trying to setup pentaho spoon to connect to AWS auora which on a vpn in AWS.   I have access to AWS auora ( mysql ) through a bastion server.   It is working with mysql workbench and a simple java program.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/estimates", "root", "xxxxxxx");
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
String strSelect = "select first from test_name";

ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(strSelect);
int rowCount = 0;
while (rset.next()) {  
    String first = rset.getString("first");
    System.out.println(first);
    ++rowCount;
}
```

with pentaho this error:

```
Error connecting to database [t1] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Exception while loading class
org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Exception while loading class
org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver


    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:366)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:315)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:277)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:267)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:86)
```

I have loaded the jdbc driver in the ..\data-integration\lib.

What could I be missing? Or is it a problem with this version of pentaho  4.4.0-stable?

Comment: Boy oh boy, 4.4 ? Unless you're using self made patches to that version, use Version 7.0

Answer (score 0):

I used an older jdbc driver  aand it worked with this version of pentaho

https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-j/